# The panel or buttons aren't being displayed on the frame

Tags: java, button, panel, frame

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JButton[][] buttons;

private JPanel otherPanel;

public Frame() {
    setSize(500, 600);
    setLocation(100, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
    buttonPanel.setSize(500, 500);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
    buttons = new JButton[8][8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton("" + i);
            buttonPanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
        }
    }
    add(buttonPanel);
}

}
```

the buttons are supposed to be put on the panel and then the panel is put on the frame. when its run however nothing is shown on the frame
thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide a compileable example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: just do Frame f = new Frame() and it will run now

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at where you're setting the JFrame visible. And then look at where you're adding your buttons. Kind of out of order, don't you think? It's like taking a picture of a chair, and then after doing that, asking someone to sit in the chair. If you want to take a portrait, have them sit in the chair *first*, and *then* take the picture. Call `setVisible(true)` **after** adding all components.
2. Get rid of your use of null layout as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. Instead you will want to study and learn the layout managers and then nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to create pleasing and complex GUI's that look good on all OS's.

Comment: 1. That worked thank you  2. what layout would you reccomend then for a frame that would just contain two side by side panels?

Comment: @DerekSchuster `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, `BorderLayout` all would be capable of doing this

Answer (score 0):

where is the main ?
also you have to make an object from JFrame and use it to add these methods, example JFrame f=new JFrame;
f.setSize(..,..);
and so on..

Comment: the main is in another class and no you dont have to have that